# Замена нескольких разных значений в 1-м поле

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте уважаемые. Есть следующая таблица:

[image: таблица]

Нужно заменить все `store_id = 1` на "Восток", а `store_id = 2` на "Запад". Я попробовал через `replace`, но через него можно лишь 1 какое-то значение менять. Заранее благодарен.

Должен быть написан запрос, который выводит customer_id, last_name и store_id. Но вместо store_id должен быть либо "восток" для store_id = 1, либо "запад" для store_id = 2

Я пробовал писать что-то вроде:

```
SELECT customer, firstname, replace(store_id  = 1, 'Восток') FROM customer
```

Запрос работает, но он заменяет лишь все для `store_id = 1`. А вот как сделать, чтоб `replace` работал для двух значений - понятия не имею.

Comment: А вы `UPDATE` попробуйте ещё.

Comment: 1. текст всегда лучше распространять в виде текста, а не изображения. 2. а где именно в приведённом примере должны быть записаны строки «восток» и «запад»?

Comment: Вам нужен банальный `JOIN` c таблицей, в которой у Вас прописаны эти соответствия между `store_id` и `store_name`.

Comment: А без него это нереализуемо?

Comment: Может быть и реализуемо, но в извращениях я Вам не помощник, уж извините. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно использовать `case`:

```
SELECT 
  customer, 
  firstname, 
  case 
    when store_id = 1 then 'Восток'
    when store_id = 2 then 'Запад'
  end 
FROM customer
```

[Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/29392)

---

`Join` использовать тоже не проблема [Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/29393)